# Jenkins email subject not translating environment vars

Tags: jenkins

I have a default subject set-up which uses the format,

$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!

This used to output the values of the env vars, but now just outputs the env var names.

Is there a different way of including env vars in emails now?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you sending the Email?

Comment: Extended E-mail Notification and Editable Email Notification.
The emails are sent ok, but the environment variables are not being translated.
It was working, so I can only assume a plugin has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Groovy string interpolation:

```
${PROJECT_NAME} - Build # ${BUILD_NUMBER} - ${BUILD_STATUS}!
```

But as it was working before, it may be something similar to [this](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-65465) and the suggested solution is to update the Token Macro plugin to 2.14 or later.